# Recursive function in MIPS

Tags: mips

I'm new on this site and in mips.I am trying to make the sum of the squares of a number without it, for example, f(4) = 9 + 4 + 1 = 14. This is a part of my code, the recursive function exactly.

```
RecursiveFunction:
            subu $sp, $sp, 8
            sw $ra, ($sp)
            sw $s0, 4($sp)

            li $v0, 1
            beq $a0, 0, Done

            move $s0 $a0
            sub $a0, $a0, 1
            jal RecursiveFunction
            move $t0, $v0
            sub $t0, $t0, 1
            mul $v0, $t0, $t0
            add $v0, $s0, $v0

            Done:
                lw $ra, ($sp)
                lw $s0, 4($sp)
                addu $sp, $sp, 8
                jr $ra
```

Can u help me guys? I try to solve it for 3 days.

Comment: What does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always helps to have high-level pseudocode before attempting to translate it to MIPS.

In this case, the pseudocode that you are looking for is -

```
RecursiveFunction(n):     // return 1*1 + 2*2 + .. + n*n
  if n == 0 return 0
  else return n*n + RecursiveFunction(n-1)
```

To compute *RecursiveFunction(4)*, simply call *RecursiveFunction(3)*. The task remains to translate this to MIPS. *The key idea is using the MIPS stack ($sp) to 'remember' return address ($ra) and 'interim' values (n*n) in this case.*
 Following is the MIPS code with comments describing what each line does:

```
.text

li    $a0, 3
jal   RecursiveFunction               # compute RecursiveFunction(3)

move  $a0, $v0 
li    $v0, 1
syscall                               # and print the result

exit:
li    $v0, 10
syscall

# input : $a0 = n
# output: $v0 = 1*1 + 2*2 + .. + n*n
RecursiveFunction:
addi  $sp, $sp, -4                    # create space on stack
sw    $ra, 0($sp)                     # and remember the return address ($ra)

beqz  $a0, return0                    # if n == 0 goto return0

mul   $s0, $a0, $a0                   # else, $s0 = n*n
addi  $sp, $sp, -4                    # create space on stack
sw    $s0, 0($sp)                     # and save n*n on it

addi  $a0, $a0, -1
jal   RecursiveFunction               # compute $v0 = RecursiveFunction(n-1)

lw    $s0, 0($sp)                     # $s0 = restore n*n from stack
addi  $sp, $sp, 4                     # and reset the stack

add   $v0, $v0, $s0                   # $v0 += n*n (it earlier had RecursiveFunction(n-1))
j     exitFn                          # and jump to exitFn

return0:                              # base case (n = 0)
move  $v0, $zero                      # $v0 = 0 (the return value)
j     exitFn                          # and jump to exitFn

exitFn:
lw    $ra, 0($sp)                     # at exit, restore the return address in $ra
addi  $sp, $sp, 4                     # restore stack
jr    $ra                             # and jump to caller
```